# Campos no obligatorios usando Django Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Buenas tardes estoy creando un formulario para crear clientes en Django 1,10 usando `forms` que trae el Framework. Este formulario trae unos campos que NO son obligatorios pero al momento de guardar me pide que los complete. ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Dejo el código:

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from apps.generales.models import Cliente

class clientesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente

        fields = [
            'tipo_cliente',
            'nombre',
            'numero_documento',
            'direccion',
            'barrio',
            'telefono',
            'email',
            'ciudad',
            'nombre_contacto1',
            'telefono_contacto1',
            'nombre_contacto2',
            'telefono_contacto2',
            'nombre_contacto3',
            'telefono_contacto3',
        ]

        labels = {
            'tipo_cliente':'Tipo de Cliente',
            'nombre':'Nombre completo o razón social',
            'numero_documento':'Numero de identificación',
            'direccion':'Dirección',
            'barrio':'Barrio',
            'telefono':'Teléfono',
            'email':'Em@il',
            'ciudad':'Ciudad',
            'nombre_contacto1':'Nombre de Contacto',
            'telefono_contacto1':'Teléfono',
            'nombre_contacto2':'Nombre de Contacto 2',
            'telefono_contacto2':'Teléfono',
            'nombre_contacto3':'Nombre de Contacto 3',
            'telefono_contacto3':'Teléfono',
        }

        widgets = {
            'tipo_cliente':forms.Select(),
            'nombre':forms.TextInput(),
            'numero_documento':forms.TextInput(),
            'direccion':forms.TextInput(),
            'barrio':forms.TextInput(),
            'telefono':forms.TextInput(),
            'email':forms.TextInput(),
            'ciudad':forms.Select(),
            'nombre_contacto1':forms.TextInput(),
            'telefono_contacto1':forms.TextInput(),
            'nombre_contacto2':forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': False}),
            'telefono_contacto2':forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': False}),
            'nombre_contacto3':forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': False}),
            'telefono_contacto3':forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': False}),
        }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Crear</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes especificar en el metodo constructor que los campos no son obligatorios

en tu form

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # asi vuelves tus campos no requeridos
    self.fields['nombre_del_campo'].required = False  # solo con los campos que especificaste en la clase Meta
```

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión, debes delegar la tarea de aceptar o rechazar un campo vacío a la base de datos, porque esa es su tarea y no recargas a la vista de formularios y mucho menos confías en en HTML esa responsabilidad.

Para hacer esto, solo tienes que definir **en tu modelo** que un campo puede estar vacío y lo debes hacer *explícitamente* ya que por definición todos los campos en un modelo son obligatorios. Para hacer esto, se usa el parámetro `blank=True` en campos tipo Texto o `null=True` para campos tipo Fecha o Numéricos.

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    ...
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    edad = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ...
```

Esta es, en mi opinión, la forma más segura de hacer estas validaciones.

- Esta es la documentación de `blank`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/fields/#blank
- Esta es la documentación de `null`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null